# how to solve the error: ")" expected in java?

Tags: java

When I run my programming, it said there are some errors about ")" expected. I know what it was meaning, but I do not know how to correct it. The below codes are about my programming, please help me... Thank you!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Ex1_3 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
  
     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
     double kg = in.nextDouble();
     double m = in.nextDouble();
     double bmi = kg/(Math.pow(m,2));

     if (bmi < 18.5) {
        system.out.println("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f", kg, m, bmi "(underweight)");
     } else if (18.5 <= bmi < 25) {
        system.out.println("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f", kg, m, bmi "(normal)");  
     } else if (25 <= bmi < 30) {
        system.out.println("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f", kg, m, bmi "(overweight)"); 
     } else if (bmi >= 30) {
        system.out.println("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f", kg, m, bmi "(obese)");
     }
  
   }
}
```

Comment: `system.out.println` should be `system.out.printf`. Also you can do this: `double bmi = kg/(m*m);`.

Answer (score 5):

Here:

```
} else if (18.5 <= bmi < 25) {
```

should be:

```
} else if (18.5f <= bmi && bmi < 25) {
```

also:

```
} else if (25 <= bmi < 30) {
```

should be:

```
} else if (25 <= bmi && bmi < 30) {
```

You can't express range condition as `18.5 <= bmi < 25` or `25 <= bmi < 30` in Java. You need to break it down into conbination of two conditions.

And, there are also errors in printing. You are supposed to use [`String.format`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-):

```
if (bmi < 18.5) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f %s", kg, m, bmi, "(underweight)"));
} else if (18.5 <= bmi && bmi < 25) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f %s", kg, m, bmi, "(normal)"));  
} else if (25 <= bmi && bmi < 30) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f %s", kg, m, bmi, "(overweight)")); 
} else if (bmi >= 30) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f %s", kg, m, bmi, "(obese)"));
}
```

Comment: If I have a lot of this in a program, I'll often write a `public static bool isBetween(int left, int target, int right)`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your desired output, and I don't have commenting privileges yet, so here are some tips which I think you can use to get your desired output:

```
if (bmi < 18.5) {
        system.out.println("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f", kg, m, bmi "(underweight)");
```

on BlueJ is yielding:

[image]

The green text is String, and you can see that you are actually trying to print string and non string variables without concatenating them with `+`. For example,

```
int kg= 10
System.out.println("BMI ="+kg);
```

will give the output `BMI = 10`

That addition sign is necessary for concatenating more than one elements inside the `System.out.println()` or `System.out.print()` function.

Moreover, if you want to print quotes within the print statement, such as your output is, for e.g.;

`My "BMI" is 10 kg`

The code will be

```
int kg=10;
System.out.println("My \"BMI\" is "+kg+" kg");
```

The `\"` used is an [Escape sequence](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/escape-sequences-in-java/).

Moreover, `System.out.println()` begins with an uppercase S.

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help!  Hope you have a good day!

Comment: No problem! It would be kind of you to accept the answer if you think it solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here's the preferred way to code it:

```
String category;
if (bmi < 18.5) {
    category = "(underweight)";
} else if (bmi <= 25) {
    category = "(normal)";
} else if (bmi <= 30) {
    category = "(overweight)"; 
} else {
    category = "(obese)";
}
System.out.printf("%1.2f kg, %1.2f m, BMI = %1.2f %s\n", kg, m, bmi, category);
```

No need to check `bmi >= 18.5` in the second `if` because values of less than `18.5` is covered by the first `if` and so forth.

Notice the use of a separate variable `category` because that's the only value that changes in all the `if`s. Also Java has a `System.out.printf` method for a long time. Note that you need to add a `\n` at the end of the string pattern to be equivalent to the `println`.